# How to group EC2 instances in order to delegate administration to different teams?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is it possible (using ARN) to make several groups of instances.
Then using different policies to grant access to a group of instance only and not the other instances?

For example :

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "autoscaling:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead of "*" could we use a group or something like that? like a specific subnet? a Tag? or whatever...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

No EC2 doesn't provide any way to do this with instances. ARN resource names are only available for products that are listed with a check in the Resource column and there is no other method of filtering out resources.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_SpecificProducts.html